# "stack setup --upgrade-cabal" fails, can't find Text.Parsec

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

After creating a new project using `stack new testProject`, I have edited `testProject.cabal` to use the latest version of Cabal:

```
cabal-version:  2.2.0.0
```

Running `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` afterwards produces an error:

```
[ 12 of 216] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Parsing ( Distribution/Compat/Parsing.hs, Distribution/Compat/Parsing.o )

Distribution/Compat/Parsing.hs:61:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
61 | import qualified Text.Parsec as Parsec
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exit code ExitFailure 1 while running ["ghc","Setup.hs"] in /tmp/stack-cabal-upgrade30389/Cabal-2.2.0.0/
```

I'm on Arch Linux 4.15.3, `stack --version` gives

```
Version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
```

`stack ghc -- --version`:

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2
```

How can I get around this error and upgrade Cabal using Stack?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using Stack rather than the standard `cabal` tooling? Note also that you don't need to set `cabal-version: 2.2` unless you need features (such as e.g. "`common` Stanzas" or the new `elif` keyword) for your package specification that are only available with that cabal spec-version. C.f. http://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-projectindex.html

Comment: The `common` stanzas are the very motivation I'd like to upgrade to `2.2`. I have no reason to use Stack, apart from the [Haskell book](http://haskellbook.com/) recommending it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you describe happens because:

1. *Cabal* 2.2.0.0, unlike the earlier versions, has *parsec* as a dependency. To account for that, [*parsec* is one of the core packages bundled with GHC from GHC 8.4.1 onwards](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/8.4.1-notes.html#included-libraries).
2. `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` installs *Cabal* at a "global" level, which is cross-snapshot but tied to the GHC version. As a consequence, it only uses packages bundled with GHC (as opposed to packages in any snapshot). See [Stack issue #3049](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3049) and the other issues linked therein for discussion of this point.

That being so, I believe there is no solution to this issue, unless you are willing to change your project to a resolver/snapshot that uses GHC 8.4.1.

P.S.: Unless you need a specific *Cabal* feature or bugfix included in 2.2.0.0, you may want to reconsider whether you actually want to upgrade *Cabal*. Quoting the [Stack user guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#power-user-commands):

> `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` can install a newer version of the Cabal library, used for performing actual builds. You shouldn't generally do this, since new Cabal versions may introduce incompatibilities with package sets, but it can be useful if you're trying to test a specific bugfix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't have a pressing need to upgrade Cabal to `2.2`; I was merely interested in simplifying my Cabal file using the `common` stanzas introduced in `2.2`. For now I'll postpone upgrading Cabal (or abandoning Stack).